# C++ Error C2660: Function does not take 3 arguments

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I'm racking my brain to figure this out.. I know its something simple but I need a new set of eyes to figure out what I'm missing?

Line contains ** below, 7th line from the bottom

I'm getting an error C2660: 'drillOneProblem' : function does not take 3 arguments. Help Please!

```
// Drill into problem
void drillOneProblem()
{
int c, r1, r2; // passed-in parameters
int CorAns; // correct answer
int reply; // user's answer

// Ask first part of question and display first random number
cout << "\nWhat is " << r1;

// Display sign based on user's answer
switch (c)
{
    case '1': cout << " + ";
    CorAns = r1 + r2;
    break;
    case '2': cout << " - ";
    CorAns = r1 - r2;
    break;
    case '3': cout << " * ";
    CorAns = r1 * r2;
    break;
}

// Finish question and display second random number
// Ask answer, validate answer and display message
cout << r2 << " ? ";
cin >> reply;

if (reply == CorAns)
{
cout << "Yes, that is corret. Good job!";
}
else
cout << "No, the correct answer is: " << CorAns << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int c; // user's menu choice
    int r1, r2; // random numbers

    //Display Menu
    displayMenu();

   // Get user's choice and validate if out of range
   c = getMenuChoice();

   // Continue with program if user doesn't quit
   while (c >= 1 && c < SENT)
{
    // Generate random numbers
    Gen2Rand(r1, r2);

    // Display question based on user's menu choice request answer and validate answer. 
    // Display message to show if correct or not correct. If not correct display correct answer
    **drillOneProblem(c, r1, r2);**

    // display menu again and ask for menu choice after problem has been processed, repeat until  
    user quits
    displayMenu();
    c = getMenuChoice();
    } return 0;
}
```

Comment: declare your function as void drillOneProblem(int c, int r1, ,int r2) and remove local variables with same name inside the function

Answer (score 3):

Parameters need to be declared in the brackets in function declaration.

So this:

```
void drillOneProblem()
{
int c, r1, r2; // passed-in parameters
```

should be this:

```
void drillOneProblem(int c, int r1, int r2)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

declare your function as

`void drillOneProblem(int c, int r1, ,int r2)`

and remove local variables with same name inside the function

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the parameters in your function declaration (first line)

```
void drillOneProblem()
```

it should be:

```
void drillOneProblem(int c, int r1, int r2){
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not have the params in you declaration

```
 void drillOneProblem()
```

it should be
void drillOneProblem(int c, r1, r2);

and you should remove the varriables in you fuc,like that:

```
void drillOneProblem(int c, r1, r2)
  {
  //int c, r1, r2; // passed-in parameters
  .....
  }
```